# Translation for "Readability is one thing, legibility is another"?

Tags: sens, traduction, vocabulaire, anglais

J'ai trouvé la phrase « Readability is one thing, legibility is another » dans le livre [*Agile Documentation*](https://books.google.dz/books?id=KdAEb0MOQCwC&pg=PR14&lpg=PR14&dq=%22readability%20is%20one%20thing,%20legibility%20is%20another%22&source=bl&ots=Ex0qDPcuvR&sig=ACfU3U39Sw5yTZyLegF1nyK6sMTBU01cVA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSrM3W7-LlAhVqSBUIHZruBbQQ6AEwCnoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22readability%20is%20one%20thing%2C%20legibility%20is%20another%22&f=false) et j'aimerais bien avoir deux mots distincts de même sens que ceux en anglais, puisque la [traduction](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=fr&text=Readability%20is%20one%20thing%2C%20legibility%20is%20another) de Google renvoie à la même chose :

> La **lisibilité** est une chose, la **lisibilité** en est une autre.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

======== Sens 1 =============

Il s'agit de deux termes de *typographie*, et de *design*. Leurs différences doivent être considérées sous l'aspect du *vocabulaire technique* relatif à ces métiers.

(Surtout en ce qui concerne Legibility, qui est le plus technique des deux)

Readibility et Legibility sont intimement liés, la "Readibility" dépendre pour une bonne part de la "Legibility de la police choisie.

- Le premier, **readibility**, fait référence à la facilité, ou non, qu'a l'œil humain de suivre les lignes, de s'attarder sur les caractères pour en extraire le sens.

Avec une mauvaise police de caractère, trop serrée, désagréable à lire à cause des jambages, de la mauvaise taille, de la mauvaise couleur, de la mauvaise forme, la **lisibilité** s'en trouve affectée.

- Le second **legibility** est une mesure statistique (donc scientifique), du % de reconnaissance des caractères entre eux.
  Il s'applique à une police de texte particulière.

*Différences*:
Alors que "readibility" porte sur un texte, mis en page, et formaté, "legibility" est une caractéristique de chaque police de caractère, une mesure de son efficacité à être lue, car ayant des caractères distincts et distinguables.

https://www.sitepoint.com/typography-readability-and-legibility-part-1

*Traductions de ces termes techniques:*

On peut faire des tests de "font legibility", par exemple des tests d' "Arial legibility", ou consulter ses statistiques.

http://all-for-design.com/typographie/google-fonts-tests-de-lisibilite/

On parle de "tests de lisibilité", pour une police donnée.
C'est donc une affaire de contexte: *la lisibilité du texte* est une chose influencée par notre choix de police, notre mise en page, mais aussi par *la lisibilité de la police*.

======== Sens 2 =============

Dans un autre contexte technique, celui de l'*ergonomie* et les sciences de l'information & de la documentation,
on trouve des traductions différentes, avec des sens différents pour readibility/legibility

On parle alors de "lisibilité cognitive" pour la readibility,
et de "lisibilité visuelle" ou "matérielle", pour la legibility.

http://tecfa.unige.ch/tecfa/maltt/cosys-2/textes/ergolab_lisibilite_web.pdf

La lisibilité visuelle (legibility) consistant à optimiser l'agencement du texte, la police, la taille, la couleur, et tous les facteurs possibles pour augmenter le confort de lecture (équivalent au "readibility" typographique)

Lisibilité visuelle du texte

La lisibilité cognitive (readibility) consistant à faire ressortir le signifiant du texte, en facilitant l'extraction cognitive de l'information à partir du texte.
En détachant des paragraphes les uns des autres pour faire ressortir des idées, en soulignant des termes, etc... Mettre en valeur des informations;

Lisibilité cognitive du texte.

On peut rapproche la Lisibilité cognitive de l'intelligibilité, car tous deux font référence à la quantité d'information "digérée" et comprise,
 mais les 2 termes ne pourront pas être synonymes. Je pense que l'intelligibilité fait d'avantage référence au fond qu'à la forme, comme par exemple le choix de vocabulaire, la tournure des phrases.

Comment: Travail impressionnant. Je pense que le sens 2 convient davantage ici, étant plus général. Je comprends que c'est votre avis également !

Answer (score 6):

Je ne connais pas deux mots en français qui correspondent directement.

Dans le contexte particulier du paragraphe cité, je proposerais *lisibilité* et *clarté*, mais j'admets que cela reste imparfait.

*Intelligibilité* est possible aussi, bien que je préfère *clarté* ici.

Comment: Je pense que clarté est applicable aussi bien au choix des mots qu'à la présentation !

Comment: J'aurais dit aussi "intelligibilité" avant de lire la définition technique du mot.

Answer (score 3):

> [Lisibilité](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8408534) [*legibility, readability*] : Qualité d'un texte qui
>   se lit aisément, en raison notamment de sa disposition et de ses
>   caractéristiques typographiques.
>  [Lisibilité](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8408612) [*readability*] :
>   Facilité de compréhension d'un texte. [...] Le français ne fait pas la
>   distinction de sens que l'anglais fait entre *legibility*, facilité de
>   lecture due à la typographie, et *readability*, clarté et simplicité
>   du style.
>
> [ Le grand dictionnaire terminologique (OQLF), *lisibilité*, *lisibilité*
>   ]

On peut dire que pour une fois la traduction de Google est bonne. Le fait que la nuance ne s'exprime pas nécessairement par le même genre de dichotomie qu'en langue anglaise ne signifie pas qu'elle ne soit pas comprise. Généralement dans un cas on a la typographie et dans l'autre, le style, et il peut aussi s'agir d'emplois [spécialisés](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8359496). Probablement que des auteurs, typographes ou développeurs Français ou francophones se sont déjà penchés sur de tels sujets, malgré la haute voltige. En résumé le style c'est une chose et la lisibilité c'en est une autre...

Comment: Intéressant (+1). Il me semble que le mot *clarté* est très général. Par exemple la clarté d'une présentation peut concerner aussi bien le choix des mots, des idées que la disposition sur un schéma ou le choix d'une typographie adaptée

Comment: @Damien Sans doute. Peut-être que _clarté du style_ ou _style clair_ diffère légèrement de _clarté_ tout court. Mais il y a plus que le choix du terme pcq qu'en fait il s'agit d'en choisir 2 ou un qu'on évoque avec un autre. Ensuite il y a ce à quoi tu rattaches le tout, soit à une dichotomie p.-ê. plus traditionnelle comme avec le style, ou autrement il faut employer des adjectifs comme on le fait ailleurs. Parfois le fait que le domaine de l'informatique soit productif au lexique masque le fait qu'on ne réinvente pas la roue à tout bout de champ et on peut souvent puiser dans le construit.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of these two words as used in the text you cite (Agile Documentation) is not exactly the same as it has been before the age of computers ; in this text it is specialised to modern text treatment and apparently the established usage in this new field has not yet been recognised in French. A clue that tends to confirm this lacuna in the French text treatment outlook is the lack of a translation into French of the articles of Wikipedia in English for the two words.

[Readability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readability)

> Readability is the ease with which a reader can understand a written text. In natural language, the readability of text depends on its content (the complexity of its vocabulary and syntax) and its presentation (such as typographic aspects like font size, line height, and line length).

[Legibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legibility)

> Legibility is the ease with which a reader can recognize individual characters in text. "The legibility of a typeface is related to the characteristics inherent in its design … which relate to the ability to distinguish one letter from the other."Aspects of type design that affect legibility include "x-height, character shapes, stroke contrast, the size of its counters, serifs or lack thereof, and weight."
>
> Legibility is different from readability. Readability is the ease with which a reader can recognize words, sentences, and paragraphs. Legibility is a component of readability. Other typographic factors that affect readability include font choice, point size, kerning, cases used, tracking, line length, leading, and justification.

From these articles it can be seen that  *readability* in the world of text treatment is an all encompassing term that covers all difficulties in the task of absorbing textual information and that *legibility* is a component of  *readability*. "Readability" is the ease in understanding the text on the level *style* and *syntax* on the one hand and on that of *presentation* on the other, and "legibility" is the ease afforded by the presentation of the text to absorb the content (character shape, type of line (length, height), justification).

From this point of view it is necessary to modify the usual translation of "readability" ("lisibilité"); a good choice (suggested by this [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40297/17649) (user **Damien**) is "**intelligibilité globale**"; a translation for "legibility" could then still be "lisibilité" but a more specific term would be "**lisibilité matérielle**", a term that has not been used, as far as I know, but some such term has become necessary.

A translation of the sentence along the lines of thinking of the quoted articles could then be as follows.

- L'intelligibilité globale c'est une chose, la lisibilité matérielle c'en est une autre.
  *(Readability is one thing, legibility another.)*

Comment: Merci, d'après votre réponse je trouve que "readability" = "lisibilité"  "legibility" = "clarté" et j'accepte la proposition de @Damien en tant que traduction dans ce contexte.

Comment: @M.Abdelhafid Je ne crois pas que cela soit très juste : « clarté » est applicable à la syntaxe, au style, au choix de mots et non à la présentation, ce à quoi « legibility » est vraiment spécialisé.

Comment: L'auteur dans le troisième chapitre "Layout and Typography" a mentionné beaucoup le terme "legibility" et ça relation avec la typographie et la mise en page. ce qui rend la réponse de @Damien "clarté" acceptable dans ce contexte.

Comment: @M.Abdelhafid Le problème c'est que « clarté » porte sur la compréhension, pas l'apparence matérielle d'une chose: (TLFi) Domaine de la pensée. Qualité de ce qui est clair, sans ambiguïté, facile à comprendre. Clarté de la conscience, de l'intelligence, du jugement.

Comment: Apparemment c'est un problème de vocabulaire, mais je me demande est ce qu'il y a un jargon complet en français dans le domaine informatique pour ce genre de mots?

Comment: C'est une question que j'aborde dans ma réponse : apparemment, en France on n'a pas jugé bon de forger un vocabulaire bien spécifique pour l'instant et on se serait contenté du vocabulaire traditionnel, lequel est en plus trop maigre (une seule forme pour les deux concepts). D'après les quelques recherches que j'ai faites il n'y a rien, ce qui est la raison pour les termes que je propose et qui ne sont pas non plus -- je crois que c'est clair-- des termes courants mais des termes de mon propre cru auxquels j'ai recours pour respecter autant que possible  l'esprit des termes américains.

Comment: À mon avis, les affirmations à l'effet qu'on peut inférer une lacune linguistique ou intellectuelle de l'absence d'un équivalent français à un article Wiki en anglais répugnent à la logique, tel qu'expliqué aussi dans le cas des ngrams. D'où mon vote négatif. Parfois je crois que tu as un phénomène des « deux solitudes » pour ainsi dire, avec contenus qui ne sont pas reliés formellement parce que l'on ne sait pas les relier vu une catégorisation ou rattachement à un hyperonyme ou point de vue/domaine différent etc.

Answer (score -2):

La lisibilité est une chose, la visibilité en est une autre